# Are both of these proofs of Cayley's Theorem by Group Action?

Tags: abstract-algebra

The [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%27s_theorem#Proof_of_the_theorem), gave a proof of Cayley's Theorem, and then gave an alternative one that uses the language of group action.

However, doesn't the first proof also uses a group action, which is the group $G$ acting on itself by left multiplication. They essentially showed that the permutation representation is injective, and it is a group homomorphism by the group action axioms.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: You are correct.  It is possible to think of left multiplication as both a permutation (since $xa = xb \iff a = b$) *or* as a group action.